# Joining two data frames to turn full state names into state abbreviations in R and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

The first data frame I have includes a column for states called **state**, but some of the entries are shown as abbreviations (LA, CA, OH), while others have the full name of the state (Louisiana, California, Ohio).

The second data frame I have includes four columns with the following titles:

1. allCaps (example: ALABAMA)
2. full (example: Alabama)
3. twoLetter (example: AL)
4. threeLetter (example: Ala.)

Is there a way to join the two data frames so that the first data frame only shows the state abbreviations in the **state** column, replacing the full names with their abbreviations?

EDIT:

I'm going to include pictures, despite having been shot down for doing so before.

This is table one. Each row is a separate tweet that was sent from the respective states. I created it with this code (drawing data from a separate table called tweets):

```
tweets_per_state <- tweets %>%
  filter(country_code == "US" & place_type == "city" | place_type == "admin") %>%
  select(place_type, full_name) %>%
  mutate(state = ifelse(place_type == "admin", str_sub(full_name, start = 1, end = -6), str_sub(full_name, -2)))
```

[image]

This is table two, which I am trying to join with table one so that where table one shows "Virginia", instead it shows "VA".

[image]

Comment: Not a very sophisticated approach, but if you create a lookup table with the names in different flavors...then you can `match()` and use positional indexing to pick the column of names that you prefer. So in your case, 4 columns, and if/else statements to try matching on each column.

Comment: With the data.table package, something like `DT1[DT2, on=.(state = full), state := i.twoLetter]`. Hard to know the exact correct code since you give no reproducible example.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @Dennis You want to provide a real data rather than images. SO users do not want to type all data by hand to help you given that is a lot of work. You need to use `dput()` that gives you your data structure. For example, if your data is called `foo`, you wanna type `dput(foo)` in your R Console. Then, you will see a chunk of text. That is your data. Copy and paste it to your question. People are happy to give you hands, but you need to provide your data in a way that SO users can have an easy access.

Comment: @jazzurro, thank you for that information. I could not understand exactly what I had to do to have my question be up to standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` based solution will involve using a `dummy` column to join two tables and then using `grepl` to replace `state` column with `twoLetter` value.

I have created data.frames with few rows to demonstrate solution.

```
tweets <- data.frame(place_type = rep("city",4),
full_name = c("Los Angeles, CA", "Maitland, FL", "Indianapolis, IN", "Virginia, USA" ),
        state = c("CA", "FL", "IN", "Virginia"), stringsAsFactors = F)

      #  place_type        full_name    state
      #1       city  Los Angeles, CA       CA
      #2       city     Maitland, FL       FL
      #3       city Indianapolis, IN       IN
      #4       city    Virginia, USA Virginia

 state <- data.frame(allCaps = c("CALIFORNIA", "FLORIDA", "INDIANA", "VIRGINIA"),
              full = c("California", "Florida", "Indiana", "Virginia"),
              twoLetter = c("CA", "FL", "IN", "VR"),
              threeLetter = c("Calif.", "Fla.", "Ind.", "Vir." ),stringsAsFactors = F)

state <- state %>% mutate(dummy = 1)

tweets%>%
  mutate(dummy = 1) %>%
  filter(place_type == "city" | place_type == "admin") %>%
  inner_join(state, by = "dummy") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(state = ifelse(state == twoLetter , state,
                        ifelse(grepl(full, full_name),twoLetter, NA))) %>%
  filter(!is.na(state)) %>%
  select(place_type,full_name,state)

# Result
#  place_type full_name        state
#  <chr>      <chr>            <chr>
# 1 city       Los Angeles, CA  CA   
# 2 city       Maitland, FL     FL   
# 3 city       Indianapolis, IN IN   
# 4 city       Virginia, USA    VR
```